# Image Slideshow control for Windows Phone apps using C# and XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want a control inside my Windows Phone application that works like an image sliding control.
In the control a number of images will be placed and the control should have following functionalities:-

- Image should slide from one image to another after some time interval. (Possible with pivot Control and using DispatcherTimer)
- On swipe of finger from left to right or vice versa the image should slide accordingly. (Possible with Pivot Control)
- When the image is sliding from one image to another (either by swiping or after some time interval) the next image should be in continuation to the first one and should have a sliding effect (means should not load immediately)

I am able to make a control that solves the first two conditions of the requirement with the help of pivot control. Only problem is when we slide from one pivot item to another the next pivot item is loaded only after the swipe is complete or the ticker action is complete. There is a gap between two images while sliding. I want the images in continuation.

Same thing I tried with the Panorama control as well that gives the sliding image effect and the images are in continuation. but I am unable to change the panorama item on ticker with a sliding effect. It changes from one panorama item to another immedialtely without any sliding effect.

Please help me out in getting this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think Telerik [SlideView](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/slideview.aspx) is what you need. And for 99$ you will get a lot of good WP controls. You can download Telerik Examples windows phone app and try the Telerik controls [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/telerik-examples/fd55f526-d6f7-df11-9264-00237de2db9e)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I want same functionality as it is implemented in Telerik slideview, but is the functionality possible by coding withouut using Telerik library. I don't want to spend $99. Plase let me know if there is any other way out. Thanks

Comment: You can register for Nokia Developer program and get the tools